# How to split a string and store it in different variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

String Split
Description
Split the string `input_str = 'Kumar_Ravi_003'` to the person's second name, first name and unique customer code. In this example, `second_name= 'Kumar'`, `first_name= 'Ravi'`, `customer_code = '003'`.

A sample output of the input 'Kumar_Ravi_003' is:

Ravi
Kumar
003

That is a what I try to do but I don't understand how to split it and store individual parts in different variables.

Comment: str method, in python day one programming : str.split(). Post what you have tried and what problems you have faced.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Since you have no code to post, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow question.  "I don't know how to write this program" is out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

```
input_str = 'Kumar_Ravi_003'
second_name, first_name, customer_code = input_str.split("_")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_str ='Kumar_Ravi_003'
name = input_str.split('_')
first_name=name[0]
second_name = name[1]
customer_code = name[2]
print(second_name +" "+ first_name+" "+customer_code)
```

Comment: This really isn’t fundamentally different from the original answer. You’re just using the longhand format of assigning the values to variables instead of relying on destructuring.